# linear regression predictions with confidence interval plot in R

Tags: r

Say example data

```
library("robustbase")
data(education)
```

I create regression model

```
model=lm(Y~X1+X2+X3,data=education)
```

Now i need get plot where predicted values with confidence interval.
I.e., I want such plot:
[image]

How can I create it?

```
model=lm(Y~X1+X2+X3,data=education)
plot(model, which = 1)
```

It is not needed for me result.

Comment: https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/regression-confidence-prediction-intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lattice` package with `mosaic` package for that, like

```
library("lattice")
library(mosaic)
library(robustbase)

data(education)
mylm=lm(Y~X1+X2+X3,data=education)
pred <- predict(mylm, data=education)
df <- data.frame(Observed=education$Y, Predicted=pred)

xyplot(Predicted ~ Observed, data = df, pch = 19,  panel=panel.lmbands,
                  band.lty = c(conf =2, pred = 1))
```

[image]